# The requested resource (/springHibernate) is not available

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am getting this error as i have mentioned in title. I am making a sample application which is on angularJs, spring and hibernate. my application is working with spring, hibernate and jsp page but when I am not able to do it with angularJs. Here is the html page

```
<div ng-controller="empController">    
<form>
<label>FirstName</label>
<input type="text" name="Firstname" ng-model="emp.firstName"/>
<br/>
<label>LastName</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="emp.lastName"/>
<br/>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="emp.email"/>
<br/>
<label>Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="emp.phone"/>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="emp.id" />
<input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveEmp()" />
</form>
```

below is the code of angularJs controller

```
    function empController($scope,$http,$location) { 

     $scope.saveEmp = function(emp) {
            $http.post('add', $scope.emp).success(function() {
                //location.href = "index.html";
            });
            $scope.emp = {};
        };      

}
```

Below is the code of springController

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap map) 
    { 
         map.addAttribute("emp", new TestEmployee());
         System.out.println("calling listEmployees");
        return "editEmployeeNew"; 
    } 

         @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute(value="emp") TestEmployee emp, BindingResult   result) 
    { 
        employeeManager.addEmployee(emp); 
        return null;
    }
```

Below is my web.xml file

```
   <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class> 
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
    </servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
<context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Below is my employee-servlet.xml (snippet)

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" /> 
</bean>
```

I have searched this problem on net but nothing helped me as i am using angularJs. Kindly help me. I am new to these technologies so kindly help me with code if I am doing something in wrong way.

Comment: Use your browser's debug tools and check out the URL being called. Does it include the *servlet context path*?

Comment: Yes...it has servlet context path. http://localhost:8080/springHibernate/ This is the URl.